# vuetify v-menu closes immediately after opening form on-click event of a third party lib

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, cytoscape.js

I'm trying to integrate cytoscape into a vuetify SPA. Rendering a graph into a v-card-element is already working. What is also working is an on-click handler to navigate to a different page using the vue router when clicking a note in the graph. But when I replace the router-push with a command to open a context menu (v-menu), the context-menu never appears. I already double checked that the same context menu appears if triggered from a different place in the vue page.

Opening the context menu is implemented with a simple boolean value registered in vue which is bound to the v-model of the v-menu. By setting the value to true the context menu should open.

But that never happens when the value is set to true from within the cytoscape on-click handler.

The code is partially copied from the vuetify examples.

Here is the template:

```
<template>
  <v-container fluid>

    <v-layout row justify-center align-center>
      <v-flex xs10>
        <v-card>
            <v-toolbar>
              <v-btn @click="contextMenuOpen=true">Show Contextmenu</v-btn>
            </v-toolbar> 
          <div ref="cytoscape" class="cytoscape" style="width: 100%; height: 80vh;" id="cytopane"></div>
        </v-card>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>

    <v-menu v-model="contextMenuOpen" :position-x="x" :position-y="y" absolute offset-y>
      <v-list>
        <v-list-tile @click="doSomething()">
          <v-list-tile-title>Do Somethin</v-list-tile-title>
        </v-list-tile>
        <v-list-tile @click="doSomethingElse()">
          <v-list-tile-title>Do Someting</v-list-tile-title>
        </v-list-tile>
      </v-list>
    </v-menu>

  </v-container>
</template>
```

and the js part:

```
. . .
data: function () {
  return {
    contextMenuOpen: false,
    style: [
      {
        selector: 'node',
        style: {
          . . .
        }
      }, {
        selector: 'edge',
        style: {
          . . .
        }
      }
    ],
    layout: {
      name: 'cose-bilkent'
    }
  }
},
methods: {
  showContextMenu: function (x, y) {
    let vs = this
    this.contextMenuOpen = false
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.contextMenuOpen = true
    })
  },
  renderView: function (data) {
    let vs = this
    cytoscape.use(coseBilkent)
    let cy = cytoscape({
      container: document.getElementById(this.$refs['cytoscape'].id),
      elements: data,
      style: this.style,
      layout: this.layout
    })
    cy.on('click', 'node', function (evt) {
      vs.showContextMenu(evt.originalEvent.clientX, evt.originalEvent.clientY)
    })
  },
},
mounted() {
  . . . 
  this.renderView()
}
```

By clicking the button in the toolbar which I put in for testing the context menu would appear. What I find strange is that if the boolean value 'contextMenuOpen' is bound to the v-model of the menu and will be set to true from the on-click handler the value will be set back to false imediately. If I remove the variable from the v-model binding in the v-menu the value will stay true.

Is this a threading issue? What did I do wrong?

UPDATE: I have prepared a js-fiddle that reproduces the problem I have:
https://jsfiddle.net/gofrm76/0tkjp3rs/63/

UPDATE2: By creating a watch on contextMenuOpen and setting a breakpoint inside this watch I was able to track the source of the problem down at least a little bit using the stack trace. In fact, the menu appears for a millisecond and closes right away because of a click-outside handler executed in the menu. This would normally happen when the context menu appears and I click a second time somewhere else on the screen to close it again. In the case of the cytoscape on-click event, I apparently miss some kind of event propagation stop because the one click on the node leads to the opening of the menu and the immediate trigger of the click-outside handler.

UPDATE3: I found a config option on the vuetify v-menu that disables the ability to close the context menu by clicking somewhere outside of it. By binding another bool variable to 'close-on-click' that is initially false and will be set to true after a short delay I circumvent the handling of the second event mentioned above and the menu stays open. After the delay, the close-on-click will be set back to the default 'true' and the user is able to close the menu by clicking outside of it.

So for me, this is a solution I can work with for now. It showed also that the assumption from update 2 about the two events is correct and it also shows that the original post is misleading/incorrect: v-menu works as expected but the actual problem is that there are two events being emitted from the "third party lib" / cytoscape.

That leaves me with the question: How can I prevent the second event?

Answer (score 1):

Even though this question was asked a while ago, I recently encountered the same issue and would like to help those facing a similar issue.
So, I realized that the vuetify menu with the absolute prop only works with @contextmenu and doesn't work as expected with @click. The reason is that the way the menu works is that it checks for a click outside the menu to close the menu. Thus, when you click on another button, the button emits an event trying to open the menu but at the same time, a click outside the menu is detected which results in the menu immediately closing. This problem does not occur with context menu as no **click** is detected.
Thus the way I handled this was to just delay the opening of the menu on click so that it fires after the closing event fired when a click outside the menu is detected. A setTimeout will solve the issue.

Comment: If that is the case, close-on-click or close-on-content-click properties might also helps.
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-menu/#props-close-on-click

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE :**

After debugging your app i found that the issue has something to do with `vuetify` because your `v-menu` component was causing it .... after using a `v-show` on the previous one i found that the component had the following styles :

```
  min-width: 0px;
  transform-origin: left top 0px;
  z-index: 0;
  display: none;
```

Also ... the reason why your `contextMenuOpen` was converted immediately is because you had two statments that mutates the value on the same method (i commented the changes)

when i replaced `v-menu` with a normal div everything worked fine check it :

https://jsfiddle.net/jhuxwkec/

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. but it's not working for me. I tried v-if and v-show but here the menu does not appear, even when triggered by the button that previously worked. regarding the value of the boolean, it behaved as you described regarding the inability of the menu to reset the value back to false but again, if I am not using the 2way binding on the menu it doesn't work at all.

Comment: @gofrm alright .. Can you make a codepen or jsfiddle fork so we can easly detect the issue   ?!

Comment: thanks for this hint, I prepared a jsfiddle and added the link to my initial post.

Comment: thanks again. Your solution worked for me at least to some extent. With the div using the v-show the context menu stayed open. The problem I have with this solution is that the position of the menu isn't correct in my real application because the page layout is a little bit more complex than the jsfiddle. While this could certainly be fixed as well, on the other hand, I really want to know the root cause of the v-menu's behavior. The solution with the v-model is directly copied from the vuetify examples so one might think this is best practice. I also updated my initial post again.

Comment: about the other changes that you commented in the jsfiddle: I took these directly from the vuetify examples also questioning myself what this.$nextTick(() is good for in this case. but even the removal of these couple of lines didn't change the behavior.